# How to avoid using a var with BeforeAll

Tags: scala, mutable, specs2

Is there a way to avoid using a var when the initialization of a variable happens inside a `beforeAll` method (i.e. after the instantiation of the object) ?

I'd like to favor immutability …

e.g. https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/blob/master/src/main/1.3/scala/com/holdenkarau/spark/testing/SharedSparkContext.scala

Comment: Look at this: http://eugenezhulenev.com/blog/2014/10/18/run-tests-in-standalone-spark-cluster/ Seems to be okay, although I don't know what the implications might be in having a context initialized in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

The best way for you case is:

```
lazy val x: Type = _
override def beforeAll = {
  x = //you code
}
```

Comment: There is no `lazy var`.

Comment: this does not compile for me, it's still thinking there's a reassignment

Answer (score 0):

You can use external companion object to achieve this, scala will make sure that there is only one of those:

```
object SparkContextProvider {
    val sparkContext: SparkContext = {
         val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
         setup(_sc)
         sc
    }
}
```

you test code will have

```
trait SharedSparkContext extends SparkContextProvider {
   val sc = SparkContextProvider.sparkContext
}
```